# How to parse HTML5 tags in perl?

Tags: html, perl, html-parsing

I want parse HTML5 tag?
When i parse it complaint for `<section>` tag. I don't want it gives error.

Error is "`</section>`" tag is missing.

My Input is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="day" href="../css/main.css"/>
<title>Electric Potential and Electric Potential Energy</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="dcterms.conformsTo" content="PXE 1.39 ProductLevelReuse"/>
<meta name="generator" content="PXE Tools version 1.39.69"/>
</head>
<body>
<section class="chapter" ><header><h1 class="title"><span class="number">20</span> Electric Potential and Electric Potential Energy</h1></header>
<section class="frontmatter">
<section class="listgroup"><header><h1 class="title">Big Ideas</h1></header>
<ol>
<li><p>Electric potential energy is similar to gravitational potential energy.</p></li>
</ol>
</section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code is:-

```
use warnings ;
use strict;
use HTML::Tidy;
my $file_name ="d:/perl/test.xhtml";
undef $/;
open xhtml_file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', "$file_name" || die "no htm file found $!";
my $contents = <xhtml_file>;
close (xhtml_file);
$/ = "\n";

my $tidy = HTML::Tidy->new();
$tidy->ignore(
                text => qr/DOCTYPE/,
                text => qr/html/,
                text => qr/meta/,
                text => qr/header/
);
$tidy->parse( "foo.html", $contents );
for my $message ( $tidy->messages )
    {
        print $message->as_string, "\n";
    }
```

Error Log is:-

```
foo.html (10:1) Error: <section> is not recognized!
foo.html (10:1) Warning: discarding unexpected <section>
foo.html (11:1) Error: <section> is not recognized!
foo.html (11:1) Warning: discarding unexpected <section>
foo.html (12:1) Error: <section> is not recognized!
foo.html (12:1) Warning: discarding unexpected <section>
foo.html (16:1) Warning: discarding unexpected </section>
foo.html (17:1) Warning: discarding unexpected </section>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you want to do with it after it's parsed?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1157066).

Comment: For starters, HTML::Tiny is for parsing HTML, not XHTML ("the XML serialization of HTML")

Comment: Secondly, the error about the missing `</section>` is legitimate. That XML isn't well-formed because you have an unclosed "section" element. If you used an XML parser as you should, it'll surely throw an error. If you don't want it to do that, you should fix the error.

Comment: From [www.tidyp.com](http://www.tidyp.com): tidyp is a program that can validate your HTML, as well as modify it to be more clean and standard. **tidyp does not validate HTML 5**.

Comment: A version of `tidy` that *does* support HTML5 can be found at: http://www.html-tidy.org/ .  Note that this is just a command-line tool, without a corresponding Perl module, so you'll have to change the way you use it.

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, the [HTML::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/HTML-Valid/lib/HTML/Valid.pod) module is based on www.html-tidy.org and does support HTML5.  And it looks like it will provide you with the line number and column number that you mentioned wanting in this [post](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1157068) at PerlMonks.